# Could not load file or assembly 'JSNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error when ran on any other PC, I do not really know about binding versions ect, but I', lost here.. I found some tuts but it ask's for "publicKeyToken="" />" to be honest not even sure what to put their.

Could not load file or assembly 'JSNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is my current app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="JSNet" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="pwn4g3.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <pwn4g3.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CustomerFeedbackOptIn" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="FirstRun" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </pwn4g3.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be great, really would like to release the new version of my app tonight, been working on that dll for day's to find out that it will not run after sending a beta copy of the new app to someone then personally testing on a VM with debugging.

Comment: You cannot redirect from a reference assembly without a strong name to one that has a strong name.  Redirecting from version 1 to version 9 would also normally require an incredible amount of good luck.  You'll need to use a better reference assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is asking for a JSNet dll that is unsigned (`PublicKeyToken=null`), so that part is confusing, actually. However, it could be that your app.config is looking for the 9.0.0.0 version of the DLL with `publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"`, and it will most likely revert to looking for the unsigned version after that (thus your error). You should check your GAC for the JSNet dll. It is most likely on the PC that this is working, but not on the others. If not the GAC, it would need to be in your executing directory (but I would hope that would transfer from PC to PC). Hopefully that gives you a start?

You can also try to use the FusionLogViewer (run as an admin), and turn the logging on to see what paths are being searched for when loading the assemblys.

[Here is the MSDN on how to use the FusionLogViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)